# Difference between has to be, was to be, had to be, and should be

Tags: sentence-meaning

What are the differences in meaning between the following sentences?

All of the sentences below convey the meaning of compulsion of exercise to be carried out in three months.

> a) This exercise **has to be** carried out in three months.
>
> b) This exercise **should be** carried out in three months.
>
> c) This exercise **was to be** carried out in three months.
>
> d) This exercise **had to be** carried out in three months.

Answer (score 3):

> This exercise has to be carried out in three months.

This **MUST** be completed. There is a deadline with NO EXCEPTIONS!

> This exercise should be carried out in three months.

There is **REASON TO BELIEVE** this will be completed.

> This exercise was to be carried out in three months.

This is **NO LONGER NECCESSARY** to complete.

> This exercise had to be carried out in three months.

This was **COMPELLED** to complete. Did not meet deadline if you put emphasis on **HAD**.

Comment: In  (d), the words themselves do not imply failure to complete. Indeed, they can be used if the exercise was completed in three months.

Comment: Option (b) could also be read as, "It would be preferable for the exercise to be carried out in three months, but not necessarily so." In speech, this would be determined by inflection or stress on specific words. In writing, by context.